# Trying to install git-osx for the first time, download does nothing

Tags: git, operating-system, installation, osx-yosemite

I have made sure it is not a security issue with my computer. I am downloading the latest version. When it appears on my desktop, I click on the dmg file and it does nothing. It does not load and does not open. Any solution to this issue?

Comment: I install pretty much everything that isn't available on the App Store via Brew.  I would recommend that approach as it's scriptable.  I've installed git dozens of times on numerous machines that way.

Comment: @RobSweet I also tried to install Brew.. It appears like it's installed but it hasn't-- I then get the error bash: brew: command not found

Comment: I would focus on why brew isn't working.  Once you fix that then you should be able to install git and other things.  Since neither brew nor git install currently I'm going to guess that you are running into a permissions issue.  Are you trying to install from an account that has admin privileges?

Comment: @RobSweet yes, shouldn't be an admin issue, though it is a company-owned machine.

Answer (score 0):

Install brew https://brew.sh/
then do brew install git

Comment: command not found means that brew is not in your $PATH. on my mac, it is installed at '/usr/local/bin/brew'

Comment: How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the following line to your .bashrc (or .zshrc)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```